# Prolog: Get object or objects that do not comply a fact

Tags: prolog

Suppose I have the following facts:

```
boy(a).
boy(b).
girl(c).
girl(d).
```

If I query:

```
?-boy(X).
```

I get:

```
X=a;
X=b.
```

Which query should I use using a variable to get the objects that do not comply with the rule boy(), in this case, c and d?

I am new to Prolog, so I was thinking about using

```
?-not(boy(X)).
```

But that is not correct. 
Im using swi-prolog.
Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with `not(boy(X))` is that Prolog doesn't know what the "universe of possible choices" are for `X` in order to then test if they're a boy. The `boy` facts only know boys, of course.

One approach is to define all people in addition to the gender. For example:

```
% Define people

person(a).
person(b).
person(c).
person(d).

% Define genders

boy(a).
boy(b).
girl(c).
girl(d).
```

Then to check for all "non-boys" you would do:

```
?- person(X), not(boy(X)).
```

Depending upon how you want to organize your data, you can combine gender with person:

```
person(a, boy).
person(b, boy).
person(c, girl).
person(d, girl).
```

Then query:

```
?- dif(Y, boy), person(X, Y).
```

Or write it as a predicate:

```
person_not_of_gender(Person, Gender) :-
    dif(OtherGender, Gender),
    person(Person, OtherGender).
```

Then query:

```
?- person_not_of_gender(Person, boy).
```