# How to define `not_a_parent()` predicate?

Tags: prolog

How to create such logic in GNU Prolog? How to define `not_a_parent()` predicate?

```
parent(john,chris).
parent(mary,chris).
not_a_parent(X) :- \+ parent(X,Y).
```

The interesting answer to the similar question is [What is the logical 'not' in Prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8523608/what-is-the-logical-not-in-prolog). But I do not see how to implement it here.

Comment: See [Prolog get object or objects that do not complay a fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305191/prolog-get-object-or-objects-that-do-not-comply-a-fact/42305644#42305644)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Prolog: Get object or objects that do not comply a fact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42305191/prolog-get-object-or-objects-that-do-not-comply-a-fact)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
parent(john,chris).
parent(mary,chris).
parent(mary,suzanne).
parent(suzanne,jane).
parent(suzanne,peter).
parent(peter,rose).
parent(jerry,rose).
parent(jane,carl).

not_a_parent(NonParents) :- setof(Z,Y^parent(Y,Z),SetOfChildren),
           findNonParents(SetOfChildren, NonParents, []),!.

findNonParents([],A,A).

findNonParents([H|SetOfChildren], NonParents, A):-
        not(call(parent(H,_))),
        findNonParents(SetOfChildren,NonParents,[H|A]).

findNonParents([_|SetOfChildren], NonParents, A):-
        findNonParents(SetOfChildren,NonParents,A).
```

Result for querying not_a_parent(NonParents) is:

```
?- not_a_parent(NonParents).
NonParents = [rose, chris, carl].
```

Comment: Ah, I thought you wanted a list of all the people who are not a parent of a particular person X (e.g. john). I've edited the code, should be fine now.

Comment: Small remark - no "not" is present in GNU Prolog, I use "\+" instead. Your method is very cool - without additional facts (like person(chris)), only with predicates. I learned to cut in a very intrinsic way!

Answer (score 1):

You need to enumerate all the persons somehow. For example

```
not_a_parent(X) :- ( X = john ; X = mary ; X = chris ), \+ parent(X,_).
```

In any real program you would probably have some simple way to get all persons, and then you can do

```
not_a_parent(X) :- person(X), \+ parent(X,_).
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to get all the instances of `parent/2` such that X never unifies `parent(X,_)`.  `findall(Template, Goal, Instances)` executes the Goal until it fails and populate the list Instances with the terms that unify the Template. That way, if the list Instances is empty then `parent(X,_)` does not exist.

So your predicate would be like:

```
not_a_parent(X):- findall(_, parent(X,_) , []).
```

Comment: findall/3 is part of gnu-prolog ( the tag you used in your question). In any case the principle of the solution is explained and that version of prolog should have something similar. So you can either look for an equivalent implementation of findall or develop your own (e.g. using retractall).

Comment: findall/3 is present. GCL-2.6.7-ANSI Prolog IDE is GNU-Prolog. The result of the call of your function is No. Have you tested it?

Comment: Sure. https://www.dropbox.com/s/qwuqxsn4e6lcg5z/Screenshot_20170530_114552.png?dl=0

Comment: Great answer too. But I explained badly what I wanted. I wanted a list of all non-parents as an answer. But you gave an interesting result too.

Comment: Then rewrite your question.